# Lucene 8.6.1 Join Query is not collecting all the joined records

Tags: java, lucene

Lucene 8.6.1 Join Query is not collecting all the joined records

```
joinQuery = JoinUtil.createJoinQuery(fromField, false, toField, query, searcher,
                ScoreMode.None);
```

When the join query is executed it does not collect all the joined records.

```java
 protected void search(List<LeafReaderContext> leaves, Weight weight, Collector collector)
      throws IOException {

    // TODO: should we make this
    // threaded...?  the Collector could be sync'd?
    // always use single thread:
    for (LeafReaderContext ctx : leaves) { // search each subreader
      final LeafCollector leafCollector;
      try {
        **leafCollector = collector.getLeafCollector(ctx);**
      } catch (CollectionTerminatedException e) {
        // there is no doc of interest in this reader context
        // continue with the following leaf
        continue;
      }
      BulkScorer scorer = weight.bulkScorer(ctx);
      if (scorer != null) {
        try {
          scorer.score(leafCollector, ctx.reader().getLiveDocs());
        } catch (CollectionTerminatedException e) {
          // collection was terminated prematurely
          // continue with the following leaf
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Similar joinQuery was working in lucene 4.5.1

Do we need to write custom collector to collect JoinQuery records or any other ways we can collected it?

//Updated

when I am passing join query TermsQuery{field=associatedresourceurifromQuery=+_category:animals} in org.apache.lucene.search.MultiTermQueryConstantScoreWrapper in rewrite method than I am getting collectedTerms null and results having MatchNoDocsQuery("empty BooleanQuery"), any one have any idea, do we have to write any CustomCollector to collect join query result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an example of data which used to work as expected in 4.5.1, but which no longer works in 8.6.1?

Comment: 8.6.1 terms query is not working 
TermsQuery{field=associatedresourceurifromQuery=+((+(_category:animals) (+_category:* +(_documenttype:node -_category:animals)))}





4.5.1 Terms query is

TermsQuery{field=associatedresourceuri}  it aslo have fromQuery same categories

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and provide details there, instead of in a comment? And can you provide an example of the data (not just the query) which used to work as expected in 4.5.1, but which no longer works in 8.6.1?